# How do I go back to 12.04?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

Stupidly, I upgraded my ancient laptop to 13.04 and am now in a world of slowness. I'm running in dual-boot mode alongside Win XP. I've seen other similar requests and the answer is reinstall. My question is how? I've put my 12.04 cd in and it boots ok and asks me if I want to install but then just hangs.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is, boot through live Ubuntu 12.04, delete the partition where you have now installed 13.04 (make a backup of your important data first). Then try installing Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: After a bit more digging I used os-uninstaller to get rid of 13.04, reclaimed the disc space in Windows using Disk Management and re-installed from my 12.04 live CD. Several attempts at this hung until I unchecked the install 3rd party s/ware option.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install [Lubuntu 13.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) or [Xubuntu 13.04](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)

Lubuntu is the lightest desktop and Looks like this

[image]

Xubuntu looks like this

[image]

Both are supported here and run significantly faster than Ubuntu with the default Unity desktop.  They come with different default Applications but if there is anything in particular you want from a default Ubuntu install you can find it in the software centre.